# How do I make a 3wire splice with 2/0 wire?

Tags: electrical

How do I make a 3 wire splice with 2/0 wire? I want to tap into a service panel feed to add a subpanel.

Comment: What is enclosing this splice, or is it a direct burial application?

Comment: Also, are you splicing copper or aluminum wire?

Comment: Usually done with large split-bolt connectors, or "gurneys". Kinda sounds like this would not be a "subpanel", if you are tapping into the wires feeding the service panel. It would be *another* service panel, no?

Comment: Not a fan of the split bolts. You have to smother them in electrical tape, and that makes them hard to inspect.  I agree something is odd; this is only used in rare and specific situations, and I would have expected him to mention that.  These little short tweet-sized questions leave you wondering.

Comment: I don't like the sound of this at all! You DO NOT simply "tap into" the service panel wires. You put the sub-feed conductors on a circuit breaker.

Answer (score 1):

**Are you sure this is the right thing to do**?  It's rather unusual.  If you are feeding a subpanel from a main panel, there would be no call for doing a 3-wire splice, you put a [circuit breaker](http://amzn.to/2jFrwVn) in the main panel and feed the subpanel off that.

You would only use a 3-wire splice off the top of the panel in the rather unusual situation of having 2 panels of equal rank; i.e. two main panels.  The new panel would never be called a "subpanel" unless the panel you're tapping off of *is already* a subpanel. And the panels would be right next to each other.  In those cases, you'd use either screw-down splice blocks, or dual lugs.

---

It's difficult to infer skill from a question the size of a tweet. What concerns me is that you have the common case of adding a subpanel to a main panel, and you are freestylin' because *you know that little* about how this stuff works. I certainly hope not.

You use a breaker that snaps into the *regular* breaker spaces below the main switch, and you feed the subpanel off that.  It may be quite a large breaker, which may necessitate moving even more circuits.  *Don't same-pole any MWBCs* (and if you don't know what that means and why, you are out of your depth, and no, googling MWBC won't complete your knowledge.)

[image]

Comment: Your answer is spot-on Harper, but I'd be wary about including the second part, about splicing. Nothing about the over-simplified original question sounds correct. Simply adding double lugs to a main panel is almost never the right thing to do.

Comment: CO/ALR is only for wiring devices -- the equivalent rating for terminals is AL7CU or AL9CU

Comment: @SpeedyPetey you are quite right.  Emphasis changed.